# loading in half an array / dataset then the other half in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

lets say I have an array of 10 articles

```js
 var articles = [{
       "id": "0",
       "title": "Article 1",
       "image": "http://placehold.it/300x250&text=image 1" {
         "id": "1",
         "title": "Article 2",
         "image": "http://placehold.it/300x250&text=image 2"
       },
       {
         "id": "2",
         "title": "Article 3",
         "image": "http://placehold.it/300x250&text=image 3"
       },
       {
         "id": "3",
         "title": "Article 4",
         "image": "http://placehold.it/300x250&text=image 4"
       },
       {
         "id": "4",
         "title": "Article 5",
         "image": "http://placehold.it/300x250&text=image 5"
       },
       {
         "id": "5",
         "title": "Article 6",
         "image": "http://placehold.it/300x250&text=image 6"
       },
       {
         "id": "6",
         "title": "Article 7",
         "image": "http://placehold.it/300x250&text=image 7"
       },
       {
         "id": "7",
         "title": "Article 8",
         "image": "http://placehold.it/300x250&text=image 8"
       },
       {
         "id": "8",
         "title": "Article 9",
         "image": "http://placehold.it/300x250&text=image 9"
       },
       {
         "id": "9",
         "title": "Article 10",
         "image": "http://placehold.it/300x250&text=image 10"
       }
     ]
```

and I want to load in the first 5 then have a button to load in the next 5, how is the best way to do this in reatjs.

So far I am loading in all 10 like this..

```js
var Article = React.createClass({
  
  render: function () {
   return (
    <div>
       <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
       
       <img src={this.props.image}  alt="" /> 
      
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Delete Article</button>
       
    </div> 
   )
  }
 })
 
 var App = React.createClass({
  
  deleteArticle: function (article){
   this.state.articles.splice(this.state.articles.indexOf(article),1);
   
   this.setState(this.state);
  },
  
  getInitialState: function () {
   return {
    articles: articles 
   }
  },
  
  render: function () {
   var that = this;
   return (
    <div>
     {this.state.articles.map(function (article) {
      return (
       <Article onClick={that.deleteArticle.bind(null, article)} title={article.title} image={article.image}></Article>
      )
     })}
    </div> 
   )
  }
 })
```

but i want to load in 5 then have a button to load in the next 5 etc?

can anyone help?

cheers

Comment: Why not just have a variable that keeps track of the last loaded article then use a for loop to grab five new articles when the button is clicked

Comment: +1 @Binvention, you can have state variables to keep track of pagination. Or if all you want is continuous staggered data load, you can begin a timer in App which makes calls in an async fashion to the backend to fetch data and keeps on pushing new items in state. The backend API can return the last-item-index in every request. This information can be used by the timer to keep invoking itself. Once the data API returns no further rows, the timer should stop.